# Adwords Script For Call Only Ads With Label

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

I could not find in the Adscipts reference guide https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/ads how to reference call only ads.  I also used the below code to try to target the ads with the label "Call_Only" but it returns no results in the log While using this sample code in the Script Editor:

```
function getLabelsByName() {
var labelIterator = AdsApp.labels()
  .withCondition('Name = "Call_Only"')
  .get();
if (labelIterator.hasNext()) {
var label = labelIterator.next();
Logger.log('Name: ' + label.getName());
Logger.log('Description: ' + label.getDescription());
Logger.log('Color: ' + label.getColor());
Logger.log('Number of campaigns: ' +
    label.campaigns().get().totalNumEntities());
Logger.log('Number of ad groups: ' +
    label.adGroups().get().totalNumEntities());
Logger.log('Number of ads: ' + label.ads().get().totalNumEntities());
Logger.log('Number of keywords: ' +
    label.keywords().get().totalNumEntities());
}
}
```

The above code does not pull any of the ads with this label.  Eventually, the goal is to pause a specific call only ad at a specific time with the label "Call_Only".

Can someone point me in the right direction for how to get the labels for a specific call only ad in an ad group and possibly set it up to pause before and after a specific time?

Answer (score 0):

So in Ads scripts you have to use the idea of iteration. If you are looking at labels you must loop through all the labels with your condition... Once you have found your label you then repeat the same process on that label to find, campaigns, ad groups.....

```
function main() {
 var labelIterator = AdWordsApp.labels().get();
  while(labelIterator.hasNext()){
    var label = labelIterator.next();
        var campaignIterator = label.campaigns().get();
            while(campaignIterator.hasNext()){
                var campaign = campaignIterator.next();
                    var campaignName = campaign.getName();
              campaign.pause();
            }
  }
}
```